# concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve" for angular-quickstart on Mac OS X fails

Tags: macos, angular

I followed [the instructions on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html) to setup and run an angular-quickstart (Angular 2) project on Mac OS X 10.12. Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
% npm start

> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /Users/will/Documents/Projects/test/angular2-test
> npm run build


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /Users/will/Documents/Projects/test/angular2-test
> tsc -p src/


> angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/will/Documents/Projects/test/angular2-test
> concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"

[0] Unknown option: `-l'
[0] Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].
[1] Unknown option: `-l'
[1] Usage: tcsh [ -bcdefilmnqstvVxX ] [ argument ... ].
[0] npm run build:watch exited with code 1
[1] npm run serve exited with code 1

npm ERR! Darwin 16.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.2.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/will/Documents/Projects/test/angular2-test/npm-debug.log
```

I read all posts about angular-quickstart and mac unfortunately without finding anything that would help. I did upgrade nodejs and npm and also manually installed "concurrently" although this was probably not the problem. I can start both commands (npm run build:watch and npm run serve) separately and things seem to work ok (code gets automatically compiled on changes and the browser gets updated). So does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade your tcsh?

Comment: Hm... my tcsh version is 6.18.01. The latest version seems to be 6.20.00. Do you think that would make such a difference?

Comment: Having an other look at it, @Rishav might be right. When I 
`concurrently "npm run build:watch" "npm run serve"`
on the command line, I of course get the same error, but 
`run npm run build:watch & npm run serve`
works. Searching for "tcsh Unknown option: `-l'" shows that others have had similar problems. But I have yet to find a good solution. I'm a bit hesitant to upgrade tcsh on OSX as I'm sure this has potential for nasty side effects.